# HighCharts adding line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this simple HighCharts chart and I need to add a horizontal line by clicking a button, I added a button but the code which suppose to add a line won't work!
Can someone help please?

https://jsfiddle.net/khalifa/pskx5qLb/

Comment: Please edit your link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using chart.update() instead

```
 $button.click(function() {
  if (!hasPlotLine) {
    chart.update({
        yAxis:{
        plotLines: [{
               value: 40,
                        color: 'red',
                        width: 2,
                        id: 'plot-line-1'
            }]
      }
    })
    $button.html('Remove plot line');
  } else {
    chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('plot-line-1');
    $button.html('Add plot line');
  }
  hasPlotLine = !hasPlotLine;
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks , but for some reason it dose not work for me!
can you please edit my jsfiddle?